# Degeneration of Kaehler-Einstein metric of negative Ricci curvature

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $π:X→Δ$ be a family of compact complex manifolds such that the fibre $X_t:=π^{−1}(t)$ admits a Kaehler-Einstein metric of negative Ricci curvature for all $t≠0$. Then does the special fiber $X_0:=π^{−1}(0)$ also admit a Kaehler-Einstein metric of negative Ricci curvature?

Comment: I do not know the answer to this question, but I do have a family in mind that might be relevant.  For a Lefschetz pencil of hypersurfaces $X\to \mathbb{P}^1$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$ of degrees $d\geq 5$, the general member $X_t$ has canonical bundle isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}(d-4)|_{X_t}$.  There are finitely many singular fibers over $\{t_1,\dots,t_\delta\}\subset \mathbb{P}^1$.  For a ramified double cover of $\mathbb{P}^1$ branched over the points $t_i$, there are small resolutions of the singular fibers.  So those fibers are smooth, but the canonical divisor class is not ample on those fibers.

Comment: Related answer: Central fibre $X_0$ can admit Kähler-Einstein metric with negative Ricci curvature outside of a analytical subvariety if general fibers are projective. Let state Dan Popovici theorem: Let $π:X→Δ$ be a complex analytic family of compact complex manifolds such that the fibre $X_t:=π^{−1}(t)$ is projective for all $t≠0$. Then $X_0:=π^{−1}(0)$ is Moishezon. We know , Let $X$ be any compact complex variety. Then $X$ is a Moishezon space if and only if there is a proper analytic subset $S⊂X$, such that $X∖S$ admits a complete Kähler-Einstein metric with negative Ricci curvature.

Comment: It seems my previous comment work even $X_0$ has canonical singularites. But we must impose central fiber has mild singularities to consider KE metric

Comment: In fact $X_0$ can admit continuous Kahler-Einstein metric outside of an analytical subvariety $S$. But the sad part of story is that such $S$ may no longer be Zariski open subset.

Comment: Another sad part of story is that $X_0$ admit Kähler-Einstein metric outside of an analytic subvariety $S$. i.e $X\setminus S$, hence we must extend it as current to whole of $X_0$ and this exactly means that we extend the $K_{X_0\setminus S}$ to whole of $X_0$ . But we may have luck of extension theorem. But if the curvature be $L^2$ bounded then we get the desired result. So this tells us that find KE outside of analytical subvariety is not big deal, but if this KE be extended to whole of $X$, then we have done!

Comment: About my previous comment see the paper of S. Ivashkovich :Theorem3, Theorem4, http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/en/dms/loader/img/?PID=PPN311571026_0040|LOG_0052&physid=PHYS_0267

Comment: @Dima Now assume each $X_s$ admit Kahler-Einstein metric with negative Ricci curvature then we have a variation of Kahler-Ricci flow $\frac{\partial \omega(s,t)}{\partial t}=-Ric(\omega(s,t))-\omega(s,t)$ on each fibre $X_s=\pi^{-1}(s)$, so in this case by theorem of Yau-Aubin, we have unique Kahler-Einstein metric up to scaling , but the word of scaling, in this case, is highly non-trivial, so we get $\omega=\omega'+f(s)$, on each fibre which $f(s)$ is fiberwise constant, which may not be constant in general

Comment: .....continued:  now by taking derivative on both sides and comparing their Kahler Ricci flow equations, we get $\frac{\partial f(s)}{\partial s}=-f(s)+I_{\omega}^{\omega'}$, so if $s\to 0$, then on central fibre we must study the behaviour of the solution of this equation. Here $I_{\omega}^{\omega'}=log\frac{\omega^n}{\omega'^n}$. In fact conditions such that $f(s)$ remain constant when $s\to 0$. This may help

Comment: See Corollary 30. of the paper of Berman https://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.3717.pdf

Comment: I have a conjecture that for $π:X→Δ$ if the general fibers $X_s$ admits Kahler-Einstein metric and central fiber $X_0$ be Kahler manifold, then central fiber also admits Kahler-Einstein metric (this can be considered as new view of theorem of Kodaira)

Comment: Let me mention that the central fiber which type of canonical metric can admit. If semi-stable degenerations become smooth and we include the logarithmic differential form and if we take Kahler forms $ω_t$ on fibers $X_t$, then on central fiber $X_0$, we can think $ω_0$ is logarithmic differential form $Ω^2(\log⁡X_0)$. Read pages 6 and 7. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.0553.pdf, So if the general fibers $\omega_t$ admits Kahler-Einstein metric, then by allowing Mumford's semi-stable degeneration the central fiber $X_0$ admits twisted Kahler-Einstein metric $Ric(\omega_0)=\lambda\omega_0+[PD(E)]$

Comment: End of comment:Let me more explain my previous comment: Let  $π^0∶ (X^0, B^0) → S^0$ be a family of irreducible slc pairs$ (X,B)_t$
with ample $K_{X_t }+ B_t$. Then, possibly after a finite base change $S′ → S$, this family
can be uniquely extended to a complete family over $S$ such that the central fiber $(X_0, B_0)$ is slc with ample $K_{X_0} + B_0.$ see Theorem 1.3.6 http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783034809146 and combine with the result of https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00039-014-0301-8 . ....

Comment: .....So after base change the central fiber can admit KE metric with negative ricci curvature outside of Zariski open subset, but I am not sure we can extend such metric on the whole of central fiber after base change? But at least we can say that we can have some sort of twisted KE metric

Answer (score 1):

I am posting my comment above as an answer.  It appears that the answer is negative.

From what I can find, if $X_0$ is a compact, complex, Kähler manifold that admits a Kähler-Einstein metric, then $c_1(T X_0)$ is either positive, zero, or negative.  In particular, if $c_1(T X_0)$ has negative intersection with some closed, analytic subcurves, yet it has zero intersection with other closed, analytic subcurves, then the first Chern class is neither negative nor zero.  Thus, there is no Kähler-Einstein metric.

Now let $d\geq 5$ be an integer, and let $Y\subset \mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^n$ be a general hypersurface of bidegree $(1,d)$, i.e., the degree of a general fiber of $\text{pr}_{\mathbb{P}^1}:Y\to \mathbb{P}^1$ is a hypersurface of degree $d$, and the general fiber of the other projection is a hypersurface of degree $1$.  For a general such hypersurface, there are $4(d-1)^3$ points $s_i\in \mathbb{P}^1$ such that the corresponding fiber $Y_{s_i}$ of $\text{pr}_{\mathbb{P}^1}$ has a single ordinary double point $y_i$, and no other singularities.  Let $f:C\to \mathbb{P}^1$ be a double cover that is ramified over each of the points $s_i$ (and possibly also over finitely many additional points).  Denote by $t_i\in C$ the unique point that maps to $s_i$ under $f$.

Consider the base change $X'=C\times_{\mathbb{P}^1} Y$ with its projection $$\pi:X\to C.$$  The total space $X'$ is a complex, projective variety of dimension $3$ that has an ordinary double point over every point $x_i=(s_i,y_i)$.  An ordinary double point of a $3$-fold is complex analytically isomorphic to a cone over a smooth quadric surface.  Thus, there is a proper, holomorphic morphism $$\nu:X\to X',$$ that is a small resolution of each of these singular points $x_i$.  In particular, every fiber $X_{t_i}$ is a compact, complex manifold.  Moreover, it is a small resolution of the singular fiber $X'_i$.  Thus, it is a complex projective surface (every smooth, compact Moishezon surface is projective).  So $X_{t_i}$ is a Kähler manifold of dimension $2$.

However, the exceptional curve in $X_{t_i}$ is a smooth, genus $0$ curve whose intersection number with $c_1(T X_{t_i})$ is zero.  Thus, the compact, complex, Kähler manifold $X_{t_i}$ does not admit any Käher-Einstein metric.

Answer (score 0):

As Jason points out, the special fiber does not have a smooth negatively curved KE metrics in general (you can blow up the family along a subscheme supported on the special fiber without changing the assumptions you are working with, so certainly you can kill the property that the central fiber is canonically polarized).

For simplicity, I assume that $\pi$ is projective. Then $X_0$ admits a singular Kähler-Einstein metric (in the sense of Boucksom-Eyssidieux-Guedj-Zeriahi). This is a smooth Kähler-Einstein metric on a Zariski open subset of $X_0$ (the complement of the augmented base locus $\mathbb B_+(K_{X_0})$), with some additional global properties. 
The reason is that $K_{X_0}$, even if it may not be ample, is certainly big, for instance by semicontinuity of the function $t\mapsto \dim H^0(X_t, K_{X_t}^{\otimes m})$ for any integer $m>0$. This function is actually constant by a deep theorem of Siu, but it is irrelevant here.

Comment: Why in the world did somebody downvote this answer ?!?  Also, if an MO user correctly and completely *answers* a question, as in this case, why does the OP not accept the answer?