# Derivative of the flow for ODEs on manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $\mathbf V \colon [0,T] \times \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$ (for $T>0$) be a given, bounded smooth vector field and let $\mathbf X=\mathbf X(t,x)$ be its *flow*, i.e. the unique solution to the initial-value problem
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \mathbf X(t,x) = \mathbf V(t,\mathbf X(t,x)) & \text{ in } (0,T) \times \mathbb R^d \\
\mathbf X(0,x) = x \quad \text{ for all } x \in \mathbb R^d.    
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

A well-known result in standard ODE's theory says that 
$$\tag{1}
\nabla_x \mathbf X(t,x) = \exp\bigg( \int_0^t \nabla \mathbf V(s,\mathbf X(s,x))\,ds\bigg).   
$$

> Is there an analogous formula to (1) for ODEs driven by (smooth) vector fields *on Riemannian manifolds*? In particular, does this formula involve somehow the geometry of the Riemannian manifold? 
>   A rather precise question could be: consider the $C^1$ norm of $\mathbf X$ (or even its Lipschitz constant) w.r.t. space variable $x$: does it depend on some known tensors on the manifold (e.g. curvature)?

I have gone through books in differential geometry/differential topology (e.g. Lee, Lang) and they prove that $\mathbf X$ is smooth but do not compute explicitly the derivative.

References are very much welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest migrating this math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Oh, ok I thought it was suited for MO and thus I put it here. I do not have an account on SE, what shall I do in order to migrate the post?

Comment: Go to math.stackexchange.co, and try registering using the same information you use for MO.  I'm not sure about migrating.

Comment: Anyway, the answer is do everything with respect to local co-ordinates.

Comment: Ok thanks, if this is the case I will directly delete the question instead of migrating. Anyway, I apologize but I am not fully convinced that it is enough to do everything in local coordinates: for issues like existence/uniqueness OK, but shouldn't geometry be somehow involved in the derivative of the flow? I mean why should the derivative of the flow of a vector field on a sphere solve the Liouville equation? Doesn't it matter which Riemannian metric/connection are we using? That was the meaning of the question and it seems strange to me that geometry does not play any role... Thanks.

Comment: When solving for integral curves (the flow) of a vector field on a manifold, no geometric structure (connection, metric, etc.) is needed at all. What you want to check is that any solution with respect to one set of local coordinates is also a solution with respect to any other set of local coordinates.

Comment: This is probably covered in any differential geometry or differential manifolds textbook. I suggest looking at Lee's book, Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.

Comment: A family of diffeos $\phi\colon M\to M$ lifts to a family $T\phi\colon TM \to TM$, the Jacobian of $\phi$, which is linear on the fibers of $TM$. The analog of the determinant here is the [induced map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Exterior_algebra) $\Lambda^n T\phi\colon \Lambda^n TM\to \Lambda^n TM$ ($n=\dim M$). Differentiating both $T\phi$ and $\det T\phi$ with respect to the family parameter gives vector fields $TM\to T(TM)$ and $\Lambda^n TM\to T(\Lambda^n TM)$. The relation between the latter two should be a kind of "trace", though I don't know it's precise nature off hand.

Comment: I would like to kindly ask to the moderators to consider re-opening this question, as it has been largely edited and may still be of interest, as the comments below macbeth's answer testify. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be interested in this remarkable, recent [paper](http://cvgmt.sns.it/media/doc/paper/3769/Ahlfors-final.pdf) by E. Brué and D. Semola (see in particular Theorem 3.11 which answers to your question in a much more general setting).

Answer (score 8):

As was pointed out by Deane Yang and Igor Khavkine in the comments, this feels like a fact that should be "looser" than Riemannian geometry.  Indeed, as I will show below, your formula makes sense in the broader setting of smooth manifolds equipped with a volume form.  I don't know a reference for this fact.

If $(M, \Omega)$ is a manifold equipped with volume form, ${\bf V}\in \operatorname{Vect}(M)$ is a vector field on $M$, and ${\bf X}_t:M\to M$ is the flow of ${\bf V}$, then:

1) One has  $J_t\in C^\infty(M)$, (i.e., a smooth  $J:\mathbb{R}\times M\to M$), with $J_0\equiv 1$, given by, 
$$J_t(x)=(\Omega_x)^{-1}\otimes \Omega_{{\bf X}_t(x)}\otimes \Lambda^n(d{\bf X}_t|_x),$$
well-defined since $\Lambda^n(d{\bf X}_t|_x):\Lambda^n( T_xM)\to \Lambda^n (T_{{\bf X}_t(x)}M)$ as Igor said.

2) One has a well-defined $\operatorname{div}({\bf V})$, namely (up to a sign, I forget whether $\pm$)
$$\operatorname{div}({\bf V})=d(\iota_{\bf V}\Omega)/\Omega.$$

So the "hopefully-an-identity" 
$$\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right\rvert_{t=0}J_t=\operatorname{div}({\bf V})$$
(for simplicity I state just the $t=0$ formula) is well-formed.  You can then prove it by choosing local co-ordinates in which $\Omega\equiv 1$.  (There is surely an intrinsic proof, too, but I can't think of one now.)

**Afterthought, 30 Oct:**  I imagine the intrinsic proof consists of identifying both sides with the Lie derivative $(\mathscr{L}_{\bf V}\Omega)/\Omega$.

**Update, 30 Oct, in response to questions of OP in comments:** If I calculate correctly, then yes, the formulas 
\begin{align*}
\frac{dJ_t}{dt}(x)&=\operatorname{div}({\bf V})|_{{\bf X}_t(x)} J_t(x)\\
J_t(x)&=\exp\left(\int_0^t\operatorname{div}({\bf V})|_{{\bf X}_s(x)}ds\right)
\end{align*}
are also correct.

And yes, although the formula for "$\tfrac{d}{dt}\left[\det\left(d{\bf X}_t\right)\right]$" depends only on the volume form, I think one needs a Riemannian metric $g$ in order to make sense of "$\tfrac{d}{dt}\left[d{\bf X}_t\right]$" (really, the $g$-covariant derivative $D_t$ of the section $d{\bf X}_t$ of the bundle $T_x^*M\otimes TM$ along the curve ${\bf X}_t(x)$).  Probably 
$$D_t\left[d{\bf X}_t\right]|_{t=0}=\nabla {\bf V},$$
where $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection of $g$.  (Please check this calculation before relying on it!)

Comment: There is a corollary of this fact which, I think, is better-known:  the flow of ${\bf V}$ preserves a volume form if and only if ${\bf V}$ is divergence-free with respect to that volume form.

Comment: I need to apologize to the OP. I didn't read the details carefully enough. I only saw "differential dependence on the initial data". Here are two quick comments: 1) I find it easier to view $\mathbf{X}$ as a diffeomorphism between two different manifolds (and use different letters for the local coordinates in each manifold). 2) I still recommend working everything out in local coordinates first and figuring out the coordinate-free version afterwards.

Comment: Another quick observation, essentially restating what macbeth says: If you fix volume forms in the domain and range (just one is needed if the domain and range are the same), then the determinant of the Jacobian is a well-defined function on the domain. Therefore, its directional derivative also does not require a connection. This all doesn't even require that the map be a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind posts. I need some time to digest everything, as I am not so familiar with diff geom but in any case the picture is rather clear - and surprising to me. I did expect geometry of the manifold enters into the play here. May I ask you if there are aspects of ODEs theory on manifolds relying ultimately on geometric properties of the manifold? Existence, uniqueness and even the derivatives of the flow are independent of that... I know it may seem a broad question, but I really felt like sooner or later ODEs theory on manifold should face geometry... am I mistaken?

Comment: Yet one doubt: O.K. for Liouville equation. But what can we say on the whole derivative of the flow? At the end in Euclidean space it holds $\nabla \mathbf X_t = \exp (\int_0^t \nabla_x b(s,\mathbf X_s)\, ds)$. What happens on manifolds? Does this depend on the exponential map? Thanks.

Comment: @macbeth , Life is more complicated on the variational case : see my comments here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277168/degeneration-of-kaehler-einstein-metric-of-negative-ricci-curvature#comment702030_277168 we don't have uniqueness.

Comment: @macbeth , another example for Sasakian manifolds (which claim more than 100 papers are wrong)In fact the correct notion of Sasaki-Einstein metric is $Ric^T(\omega)=-\Phi\omega^T$ where $\Phi$ is a function but it is constant on each leaf $\mathcal F_x$, in fact by another point of view, if even you take  $Ric^T(\omega)=-\omega^T$ , then the solutions are constant up to scaling 
But the "word" of scaling here is more complicated! in Sasakian setting

Comment: ... and hence for two solution $\omega$ and $\omega'$, we have $\omega=\omega'+C(s)$ which $C(s)$ is constant on each leaf but in general is not constant on the whole of $X$(you can see it as distribution) so $\frac{\partial C(s)}{\partial s}=-C(s)+\mathcal I$
where $\mathcal I$ is a functional and some additional condition on it gives a precise solution to the MA equation. Moreover, K-stability for Sasakian manifolds is highly non-trivial and we just can say "WE DON'T KNOW"

Comment: @macbeth Ok, thanks for your edits, I will check and work on them. So in the end it seems that the full derivative $\nabla_x \mathbf X$ does depend on the geometry, right? This seems interesting to me and that was the kind of thing I was looking for (and which I was asking references for). Thanks!

Comment: @HassanJolany I do not know what Sasakian manifolds are. Are they smooth (Riemannian) manifolds?

Comment: Igor -- Thanks for the edit, you are right, of course.

Comment: @user111164 You're welcome.  Unfortunately I don't know references for these formulas (and therefore, by the way, I disagree with the designation of the question as "off-topic").  If there exists a book on dynamical systems specifically on Riemannian manifolds, that might be a good bet.  The formulas might also turn up in a book on Morse theory, at least in the case $V=\nabla f$.

Comment: I am back, sorry for my delay. Concerning the last formula you wrote, $D_t [dX_t]_{t=0} = \nabla V$: is it possible to derive something more general like $D_t [dX_t] = \nabla V dX_t$? I need to brush things a bit up in diff. geometry, but in $\mathbb R^n$ the equation we get for the jacobian is $D_t \nabla X = \nabla V \nabla X$ so I would expect $dX_t$ appears also on RHS in the equation on a Riemannian manifold... And btw is the exponential map appearing here? Thanks again for your help. P.S. bibliographical research was unfruitful... :-(

Comment: @DeaneYang There was a flag asking to consider reopening this question. In view of your apology in a comment above, do you think the question should be reopened?

Comment: I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @DeaneYang and moderators: thanks for re-opening my question.