# No-magnus solution to first variational equation

Tags: reference-request, differential-equations

Quoting from [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/284718/derivative-of-the-flow-for-odes-on-manifolds) question:

*Let $\mathbf V \colon [0,T] \times \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$ (for $T>0$) be a given, bounded smooth vector field and let $\mathbf X=\mathbf X(t,x)$ be its *flow*, i.e. the unique solution to the initial-value problem
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \mathbf X(t,x) = \mathbf V(t,\mathbf X(t,x)) & \text{ in } (0,T) \times \mathbb R^d \\
\mathbf X(0,x) = x \quad \text{ for all } x \in \mathbb R^d.    
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

A well-known result in standard ODE's theory says that
$$\tag{1}
\nabla_x \mathbf X(t,x) = \exp\bigg( \int_0^t \nabla \mathbf V(s,\mathbf X(s,x))\,ds\bigg).   
$$*

I have trouble finding a reference for this "standard" result. Teschl ("Ordinary differential equations and Dynamical Systems") proves the smoothness of the flow $\mathbf X$ and derives the first variational equation. However, I fail to see why that equation has solution (1) without any additional assumptions - in particular $\nabla \mathbf V(t,\mathbf X(t,x))$ commuting with $\nabla \mathbf V(s,\mathbf X(s,x))$.

Is this result still true and where can I find it?